# Write Spark dataframe into delta lake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to convert Spark data frame into delta format using the example code provided by documentation but always getting this strange error. Can you please help or guide?

```py
df_sdf.write.format("delta").save("/mnt/.../delta/")
```

Error looks like:

```py
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError Traceback (most recent call last) <command-3011941952225495> in <module> ----> 1 df_sdf.write.format("delta").save("/mnt/.../delta/") /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options) 737 self._jwrite.save() 738 else: --> 739 self._jwrite.save(path) 740 741 @since(1.4)
/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in call(self, *args) 1255 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command) 1256 return_value = get_return_value( -> 1257 answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name) 1258 1259 for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(a, *kw)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
df_sdf.write.format("delta").save("/mnt/.../delta/sdf")
```

Comment: How does `sdf` help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the issue was that I was using Spark 3.0 Preview. I had to change the spark version to 2.4 and the issue was resolved.